# How does the With statement work with torch.set_grad_enabled(True) (pytorch)

Tags: python, pytorch

Hi guys I was wondering how the dunder functions `__enter__ and __exit__`which is used by the `with statement` work with `torch.set_grad_enabled(True)`. I would appreciate the explanation with some examples

Here is a code snippet:

```
for images,labels in train_dl:
      model.train(mode = True)
->    with torch.set_grad_enabled(True):
       
       images,labels = images.to(device), labels.to(device)

       
       outputs = model(images)
       _, preds_train = torch.max(outputs, 1)
       loss_train = criterion(outputs, labels)

       optimizer.zero_grad()
       loss_train.backward()
       optimizer.step()


      #stats
      running_training_loss += loss_train.item()* images.size(0)
      running_corrects_training += torch.sum(preds_train == labels.data)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Upon entering, it turns gradient calculations on.  Upon exit, it sets it back to off.  What do you mean by "examples"?

Comment: @TimRoberts
About that, I remember reading about the `with` statement requiring the dunder `enter` and `exit` functions before being able to work. Could you explain more about it?

Comment: All objects have those methods, they're usually just no-ops.  It's really not that complicated.  The PEP that proposed the feature explains it.  https://peps.python.org/pep-0343/